# Touch Event on Notification Bar icon in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, notifications, tablet, touch-event, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I just noticed some interesting behavior of the 'Select Input Method' icon on the notification bar on a Jelly Bean tablet. If you expand the whole notification bar it doesn't show up, but if you touch just the icon it shows its own menu of options. I would like to know how to do that for my icon. I tried here first but didn't see anything relevant.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

It doesn't work on a phone and I don't have an ICS tablet to test.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

applications are not allowed to control notification bar nor its behavior. all notification builder offers is suited to help you create your own notification only.